# Remove Title from Table of Contents in Pandoc epub output

Tags: pandoc, epub

I have an `html` document which I am converting to `epub` using pandoc as follows:

`pandoc -f html -t epub --css pandoc.css --standalone --toc -o book.epub book.html`

The generated `epub` book has a title page added, and this becomes the first item in the table of contents. For example, if the html is as follows:

```
<title>My Book</title>
<h1>Chapter 1</h1>
<p>One</p>
<h1>Chapter 2</h1>
<p>Two</p>
<h1>Chapter 3</h1>
<p>Three</p>
```

Then the contents will be:

```
Contents

1. My Book
2. Chapter 1
3. Chapter 2
4. Chapter 3
```

I have been able to remove the title page from the document by modifying the `default.epub3` template to not include this section - however it creates a blank page and generates an entry for it in the TOC.

Are there any ways to prevent the title being added to the TOC?

Comment: have you tried setting the title with `-M title='my title'` instead of as HTML? see also https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#epubs

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter if you use `<title>` in the html, `-M title` or `--epub-metadata` with `yaml` - they all create a title page that is added to the TOC.

Comment: ah, that sounds like https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/6097